# token expression in flat file connection

Tags: variables, ssis, expression, etl, flat-file

I have loaded the variables in the format for example:

```
where produkt = 'Muj zivot2 R' and uraz = 'Uraz'
```

and I need the output in the file name to be:

> Muj zivot2 R_Uraz

token worked for me, but it doesn't work in this case

```
" + TOKEN(" @[User::where] ","''",2) + "_" + TOKEN(" @[User::where] ","''",4) + "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
TOKEN(@[User::where],"'",2) + "_" + TOKEN(@[User::where],"'",4)
```

*Output*

> Muj zivot2 R_Uraz